# How to connect from tarantool to mysql?

Tags: mysql, lua, tarantool

I try use tarantool as application server and want connect from tarantool to mysql.

In lua i write a function:

```
local function mysql_data(query, limit)
    local conn = mysql.connect({host = mysql_host, user = mysql_user, password = mysql_password, db = mysql_database})
    local tuples = conn:execute(query, limit)
    return tuples   
end
```

but in log i see:

```
2016-03-29 17:57:37.358 [8553] main/101/grepmaillog_app.lua F> /home/lua/./grepmaillog_app.lua:12: module 'mysql' not found:
        no field package.preload['mysql']
        no file './mysql.lua'
        no file './mysql/init.lua'
        no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/mysql.lua'
        no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/mysql/init.lua'
        no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/mysql.lua'
        no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/mysql/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/tarantool/mysql.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/tarantool/mysql/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/tarantool/mysql.lua'
        no f
```

How i can install package mysql for tarantool ?

Comment: Did you install all dependencies?
i.e.
http://tarantool.org/doc/book/app/d-plugins.html?highlight=mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install tarantool-mysql package from http://tarantool.org/download.html

Comment: My Tarantool installed from EPEL by this instruction.